# Exposing a floating IP address inside an Azure Virtual Network to the outside world

Tags: azure, high-availability, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I'm dealing with the following scenario. I've got two Linux VMs on the same virtual network. High Availability is implemented through Pacemaker which maintains a floating IP for the cluster so that either VM A or VM B is reachable under that IP.

I haven't figured out a way to expose a well known port on the floating cluster IP inside the virtual network to the public internet. There's nothing in the Azure Portal that would indicate that you can forward a port for a reserved IP to an arbitrary address inside a virtual network.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your two Linux VMs will exist in a Cloud Service and hopefully you have deployed them as part of an Availability Set.  If you have made the machines operate in an Availability Set you will be ensuring that at least one VM is operational (note this isn't based on the health of a particular service on your VM).

If you have deployed both instances into a single Cloud Service then you will already have a load balancer in front of these VMs and incoming traffic will be being load balanced between the two.

While I'm not familiar with Pacemaker I don't believe you'll need to use it if you follow the standard approach to provisioning and running virtual machines in a HA configuration.  There is a good overview on how to achieve this here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/

Answer (score 0):

If in ARM, I suggest you look at adding a Load Balancer in front. That will help your scenario.